# Solace Topic Endpoint Guaranteed delivery

Tags: solace

I want to create a topic endpoint which will allow message persistence in the topic endpoint , allow multiple consumers and assures guaranteed delivery of messages

I am planning to create durable topic endpoint for the same. Is this the right approach?

As per the documentation below, topic endpoint removes the messages from topic endpoint before reading
https://solace.com/blog/queues-vs-topic-endpoints/

(refer 'Ability to read without removal' section)

Which i think should not happen in guaranteed delivery until consumer acknowledges.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Topic Endpoints only support a single consumer. It sounds like you want to create a Queue instead.

Both Topic Endpoints and Queues will not remove messages until the consumer acknowledges. The statement in the "Ability to Read Without Removal" section of the blog just means that Queues support the use of Queue Browsers which can read messages without connecting a consumer, where only consumers can access messages on a Topic Endpoint.